# Update panel doesn't work in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I am trying to show online train in my page without any refresh. So I think I have to use `updatepanel`. My panel should be updated every second.

Let explain my code.

I put this part of code in my page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load">
    <ContentTemplate>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So I put an interval function to refresh my panel like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        setInterval("__doPostBack('<%=UpdatePanel1.ClientID%>', '');", 1000);
    });
```

In my code behind I put all fetched data,

```
protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var t in OnlineTrainList)
    {
        Response.Write("<div id='train-box' style='margin-left:" + (t.XTrainLocation - 8) + "px;margin-top:" + t.YTrainLocation + "px;background:" + t.Train.TrainColor + "'>" +
                           "<span>" +
                                t.TrainId +
                           "</span>" +
                       "</div>");
        List<Sensor> PassedSensor = new List<Sensor>();
        PassedSensor = SensorRepository.FindBy(i => i.CurrentTrainId == t.TrainId).ToList();
        string color = TrainRepository.FindBy(i => i.Id == t.TrainId).First().TrainColor;
        foreach (Sensor sensor in PassedSensor)
        {
            Response.Write("<div class='CurrentColor-Sensor' style='margin-left:" + (sensor.XLocation - 1) + "px;margin-top:" + (sensor.YLocation + 8) + "px;background:" + color + "'></div>");
        }
    }
}
```

So my problem is the panel doesn't refresh .And my panel `UpdatePanel1_Load` just call one time.

Comment: thats because on your other question i told you not to use `Response.Write` with an update panel :)

Comment: Yes you are right .I should use htmlgenerator ?

Comment: well your code is pretty simple, i would simply code it all object-style. give me a sec ill show you how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your code is:

```
foreach (var t in OnlineTrainList)
{
    Response.Write("<div id='train-box' style='margin-left:" + (t.XTrainLocation - 8) + "px;margin-top:" + t.YTrainLocation + "px;background:" + t.Train.TrainColor + "'>" +
                       "<span>" +
                            t.TrainId +
                       "</span>" +
                   "</div>");
    List<Sensor> PassedSensor = new List<Sensor>();
    PassedSensor = SensorRepository.FindBy(i => i.CurrentTrainId == t.TrainId).ToList();
    string color = TrainRepository.FindBy(i => i.Id == t.TrainId).First().TrainColor;
    foreach (Sensor sensor in PassedSensor)
    {
        Response.Write("<div class='CurrentColor-Sensor' style='margin-left:" + (sensor.XLocation - 1) + "px;margin-top:" + (sensor.YLocation + 8) + "px;background:" + color + "'></div>");
    }
}
```

first thing i must bring your attention to the `id` that you assign to all those divs, it must be unique and never the same. you could use an increment variable and append it to your div's id eg: `div0, div1... etc`

now lets have a look at the first row inside the loop. what it basically has, is a `<span>` nested inside a `<div>` and containing some attributes with text.

**the Asp.Net way of handling elements would be object oriented instead of just html string:**

```
protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //clear the update panel
    UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Clear();
    //var to generate unique div id's 
    int divIDIncrement = 0;
    foreach (var t in OnlineTrainList)
    {
        //increment the id generator 
        divIDIncrement++;
        // create a a DIV element
        HtmlGenericControl _tempDIV = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        //set the attributes for the div
        _tempDIV.ID = "train-box" + divIDIncrement.ToString();
        _tempDIV.Style["margin-left"] = (t.XTrainLocation - 8).ToString() + "px";
        _tempDIV.Style["margin-top"] = t.YTrainLocation.ToString() + "px";
        _tempDIV.Style["background"] = t.Train.TrainColor.ToString();
        //create the inner span
        HtmlGenericControl _tempSPAN = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        //set the span's innerText
        _tempSPAN.InnerText = t.TrainId.ToString();
        //add the span into the Div
        _tempDIV.Controls.Add(_tempSPAN);
        //add the Div into your UpdatePanel
        UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(_tempDIV);


        List<Sensor> PassedSensor = new List<Sensor>();
        PassedSensor = SensorRepository.FindBy(i => i.CurrentTrainId == t.TrainId).ToList();
        string color = TrainRepository.FindBy(i => i.Id == t.TrainId).First().TrainColor;
        foreach (Sensor sensor in PassedSensor)
        {
            // create another div for the sub stuff
            HtmlGenericControl _tempSubDIV = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            _tempSubDIV.Attributes["class"] = "CurrentColor-Sensor";
            _tempSubDIV.Style["margin-left"] = (sensor.XLocation - 1).ToString() + "px";
            _tempSubDIV.Style["margin-top"] = (sensor.YLocation + 8).ToString() + "px";
            _tempSubDIV.Style["background"] = color.ToString();
            //add the sub stuff to the update panel
            UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(_tempSubDIV);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you i got this error :The Controls property of UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1' cannot be modified directly. To change the contents of the UpdatePanel modify the child controls of the ContentTemplateContainer property

Comment: I got the above error on this line :Line 71:                 _tempDIV.Controls.Add(_tempSPAN);
Line 72:                 //add the Div into your UpdatePanel
Line 73:                 UpdatePanel1.Controls.Add(_tempDIV);

Comment: yes sorry my bad, i wrote it all blind... should have been `UpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add()` im updating the answer

Comment: Thanks but now i got the same error:The Controls property of UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1' cannot be modified directly. To change the contents of the UpdatePanel modify the child controls of the ContentTemplateContainer property.,on this line ://clear the update panel
Line 54:             UpdatePanel1.Controls.Clear();
Line 55:             //var to generate unique div id's

Comment: yes i missed this one xD but same goes there as well

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        setInterval("__doPostBack('<%=UpdatePanel1.ClientID%>', '');", 1000);
    }); **i put this code on header tag** is it true?

Comment: yes, it should be in header, but under your link to jQuery.

Comment: No it doesn't refresh.i refresh it .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55973/discussion-between-e-a-and-banana).

Comment: All guys that have the same problem notice that .if its page doesn't refresh change my interval function to this :  <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function () { setInterval("__doPostBack('<%=UpdatePanel1.ClientID%>', '');", 1000); }
</script>